# How to get data from Jan to last month in current month

Tags: sql

I have a requirement where I need the data from Jan to last month, so for Dec 2017 I want the data from Jan 2017 - Nov 2017 , and in Jan 2018 I want the data from jan 2017 - Dec 2017, in feb 2018 I want the data from 1st Jan 2018- 31st Jan 2018, in March I want Jan 2018 - Feb 2018 and so on.

Below is my code:

```
(case when (DateFilled) between  cast (DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '19000101', '2018-01-05'), '19000101') as datetime)
    and   cast (DATEADD(D, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', '2018-01-05'), '19000101')) as datetime) 
    THEN 1 else 0 end) as numeric(10,2) [TillLastMonth]
    (Datefilled is the column with datatime datatype)
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: Please add a tag representing the name and version of database youre using

Comment: Which dbms???????????????????  The syntax is different for different dbms so tag properly if you want the right answer.

Comment: Also the query is not even complete.  Learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i am using sql 2012